# The right usage of the past perfect tense

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

Let's say I got a shop and at the front of the shop is the announcement with following text:

> ARE YOU LOOKING FOR SOME PRODUCTS? You found that place.

I think that instead of `You found that place` should I use `You have found that place`. Because I'm not talking about past and I'm meaning it right now at this moment. Am I right?

Comment: Well, "Are you looking for some products?" sounds like the worst kind of spam, but otherwise you are correct and "you have found it!" is better.

Comment: "the place" but not "that place" since the statement is referring to your place (business) not some other place.

Comment: @Andrew No doubt there are better sales pitches, but that is another topic.

Comment: @user3169  the point is that it's not effective as contemporary advertising because it sounds like a horrible third-rate website created to rip off your personal information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree: "You have found the place" seems better to me.

"You found the place" sounds American to me (I speak British English) but I may be wrong about that.

Comment: Found ´that´ would be wrong??

Comment: "You found the place" doesn't sound *terrible* to this US English speaker (you were looking for it, and you found it) but I think part of why it sounds bad is that it doesn't match the tense of the first sentence: You *are* looking for X (present) but you *found* it (past tense)?  That's why present perfect sounds better.

Comment: But this thime I asked on the definite article. Using that would be wrong in this case?

Comment: It would be grammatical, but not idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

> You found the right place

This is [past simple](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/past-continuous-and-past-simple), and normally describes an event that happened in the past that did not have any lasting consequences.

> You have found the right place

This is [present perfect simple](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/present-perfect-simple-and-present-perfect-continuous), and describes and event that happened in the past where some consequence of the event is still in force.

In this case, the customer found the right place (in the past) and is still standing in front of the shop reading the sign... the consequence of the finding still exists, because he still knows were the shop is (in front of him!). Present perfect simple is therefore the best choice, although simple past is grammatically correct.

As a side note, the idiomatic way of phrasing this kind of concept is "you have come to the right place", which also uses present perfect simple. The past simple version "you came to the right place" is also used, but is [less common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=come%20to%20the%20right%20place%2C%20came%20to%20the%20right%20place&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccome%20to%20the%20right%20place%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccame%20to%20the%20right%20place%3B%2Cc0).

> If it's songs you want, you've come to the right place - [the Big Ballad Jamboree](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=pODDZOK5T-kC&pg=PA79&dq=%22come%20to%20the%20right%20place%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNxZS3qrPWAhVDkRQKHQJPDCcQ6AEIPTAE#v=onepage&q=%22come%20to%20the%20right%20place%22&f=false)